# create xml from object

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, xml-serialization

Basically i want to create XMLDesigner kind of thing in Flex, using which user can add/edit components and properties of view/dashboard. 
i am storing view structure in a xml file. i parsed that file at runtime and display view.
How to **convert an object (having properties and sub-objects) to xml node (having attributes and elements) and add that xml to the existing xml file.** so that next time when i parsed xml file i'll get that new component in my view/dashboard.

for e.g, object structure of component in xml file :

```
<view id="productView" label="Products">
<panel id="chartPanel" type="CHART" ChartType="Pie2D" title="Productwise Sales"  x="215" y="80" width="425" height="240" showValues="0" >  
  </panel> 
</view>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an XML (de)serialization library.

There are many out there but one thing that I have used and found very stable is [FlexxB](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/). It has got a plethora of functions and I swear by it!

Flexxb is annotation based and very easy to use once you get the hang of it.

Here is a sample copied from the main web site.

```
        [XmlClass(alias="MOck2Replacement", idField="id")]
        public class Mock3
        {
                [XmlAttribute]
                public var id : Number = 3;
                [XmlAttribute]
                public var attribute : Boolean;
                [XmlElement(alias="objectVersion")]
                public var version : Number;

                public function Mock3()
                {
                        super();
                }
        }
```

You decorate each of your variables with an annotation and tell what kind of XML type would it be.

And you create the object

```
var target : Mock3 = new Mock3();
target.attribute = true;
target.id = 5;
target.version = 33;
```

And you do

`FlexXBEngine.instance.serialize(target)`

And the result would be

```
<MOck2Replacement attribute="true" id="5">
  <objectVersion>
    33
  </objectVersion>
</MOck2Replacement>
```

And the other AWESOME thing about is that you don't have to have the source of an object to decorate it.

There is an API that handle that. Using this AP, I successfully de(serialized) `SolidColor` and `LinearGradient` where I did not have the source to decorate it.

Checkout the [General Description](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/wiki/GeneralDescription?tm=6) and [Samples](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/wiki/Samples2x). And it's a [one SWC install](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/downloads/list) :)

Comment: Hi Ranhiru, Thanks for the link it is almost the same as i needed. In this first we have to define classes for each component and define their attributes and elements.Is it? What if we want to add new attributes to components for e.g. < MOck2Replacement attribute="true" id="5" fontSize="14"> 
In this case we have to first define fontSize attribute in Mock3 class. Can we do this things using flexXB?? how can i add new attributes/elements to the Mock3 class at runtime??

Comment: Yes. That is the easy way when you know all the attributes. Or else you can use the **Annotation API** to register the annotations at run time. Check the **Programatically building descriptor** section in http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/wiki/Samples2x

Comment: In that example they havn't added any new attribute or elements to the class. Can we do that using Annotation API??

Comment: Wait! So this new attribute is **NOT** there in your object but you want to add it to the XML? Or the new attribute gets added to your object at run time ?

Comment: Yes u r Right. i want to add/edit object attributes/element at runtime. basically for example < pod id="p1"> after adding new attribute at runtime < pod id="p1" type="CHART"> in this type was not declared in pod class,  or editing <pod id="pod1">

Comment: So you will be using a class defined with `dynamic`, am I right?

Comment: Actually i dunt know how to achieve this thing.

Comment: It's better to raise that concern as a separate question. But since Flexxb has the **Annotation API** you will be able to serialize it. Or else you can try using `SimpleXMLEncoder` and `SimpleXMLDecoder`. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/04/converting-objects-to-xml-packets-using-the-simplexmlencoder-class-in-flex/

Comment: simpleXMLEncoder's output is simple xml tags which dunt have attributes.

Comment: Gannesh, you should ask a different question for the concern you have about dynamically adding attributes to an object. However, given that you achieve to do so, FlexxB can be used to (de)serialize that object by using the Annotation API.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [asbeangen](http://code.google.com/p/asbeangen/) for the job.

1. You define a dtd
2. You generate actionscript model classes from the dtd
3. In your actionscript code you load your xml and fill the generated model with the values
4. You modify the model and call toXML() on it's root. That gives you a xml with the modyfied values.

Here is a more elaborate [quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/asbeangen/wiki/Quickstart).