# How to dynamically add attributes to an object and convert that object to xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, xml-serialization

How to dynamically add attributes to an object and convert that object into xml in Flex/Actionscript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create xml from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544769/create-xml-from-object)

Comment: @grapefrukt: Is it?? B-)

Answer (score 1):

You must denote the object as dynamic, then you can add any properties you want.  Then you can fall back on the

```
for (var i:String in myArray) 
{ 
   trace(myArray[i]); 
}
```

to help create your xml.